# Prove that $\overline{X}=X\cup Y$ where $X=\{(x,\sin(1/x));\;x>0\}$ and $Y=\{(0,y);\;|y|\leq1\}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\left\{\left(x,\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^2;\;x>0\right\}$ and $Y=\left\{\left(0,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^2;\;-1\leq y\leq1\right\}$. I would like to prove that $\overline{X}=X\cup Y$. I've proved that $X\cup Y\subset\overline{X}$ but I don't know how obtain the converse inclusion. Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Step 1, $\overline{X} \subset A := [0,\, \infty) \times [-1,\,1]$. Step 2, if $p \in A \setminus (X \cup Y)$, then $p \notin \overline{X}$.

Comment: Can you prove that $(1,\frac 1 2)\notin \overline X$? If so, the same technique should work elsewhere.

Comment: @dfeuer Could you give me some details?

Comment: Stefan's answer addresses it pretty generally, but my point is that if you look at this set, everything to the right of $x=0$ looks about the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several characterizations of the closure of a set. In metric spaces, I find useful:

> *Given a set $X$, $x\in \overline{X}$ if and only if, there is a sequence $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $x_n\to x$.*

So let $(x,y) \in \overline X$ (the $X$ in your question), and let $\left(\left(x_n,\sin\frac1{x_n}\right)\right)$ a sequence in $X$ which converges to $(x,y)$. Then
$$x_n\to x,\quad\text{and}\quad \sin\frac1{x_n}\to y.$$

There are two cases: $x=0$ or $x\gt 0$.

If $x\gt 0$, you know that the map $t\mapsto \sin(1/t)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and then
$$(x,y)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(x_n,\sin\frac1{x_n}\right)=\left(x,\sin\frac1x\right)\in X.$$

If $x=0$, since
$$-1\leq \sin\frac1{x_n}\leq 1\qquad \forall n$$
it must be that
$$-1\leq y\leq 1,$$
so
$$(x,y)\in \{0\}\times [-1,1].$$

This proves
$$\overline{X}\subseteq X\cup \{0\}\times [-1,1].$$

Answer (score 2):

It may be helpful to note that $X$ is closed relative to $U:=(0,\infty)\times\Bbb R$ since it is the graph of $\sin(1/x):(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$, which is continuous, and $\Bbb R$ is a Hausdorff space. This tells you that $X=\text{cl}_U(X)=\text{cl}(X)\cap U$. So each limit point of $X$ outside of $X$ itself must be in $(\infty,0]\times\Bbb R$. Since $\Bbb R^2-([0,\infty)\times[-1,1])$ is open, a limit point of $X$ can only be in $([0,\infty)\times[-1,1])-U,$ and this is precisely $Y$.

Comment: Is there any "simplest" answer? (I've never studied Hausdorff space, but only topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with analysis books).

Comment: The property of Hausdorff spaces I used is: If $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map into a Hausdorff space, then its graph is a closed subset of $X\times Y$. A proof for metric spaces (like $\Bbb R^n$) goes like this: Let $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ and $G(f)$ be the graph of $f$, that is $G(f)=X=\{(x,f(x))\mid x>0\}$. Let $(x,y)\notin G(f)$, so $y\neq f(x)$. There is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(y)\cap B_\epsilon(f(x))=\emptyset$. By continuity of $f$ there is a $\delta>0$ with $f(B_\delta(x))\subset B_\epsilon(f(x))$. Now $B_\delta(x)\times B_\epsilon(y)$ does not intersect the graph $X$.

Comment: But this proof is mainly the proof for general topological spaces (just replace $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ by neighborhoods). Note how the Hausdorff-property of $Y$ was used: Any two points can be separated by disjoint $\epsilon$-balls.

Comment: I don't think there could be a simpler answer. You always have to make use of the fact that $G(f)$ is closed, and any argument establishing this closedness will look like the argument I provided in my comment.

Comment: The hardest part of this argument, I think, is proving that the sine function is continuous.

Comment: @dfeuer: As the question is stated, I assumed that to be known to the OP. I don't think the problem can be solved without using continuity of sine somewhere. But I can't really remember when I first learned that it is continuous or how the proof looks like.

Comment: Uniform convergence, I would guess, but I don't remember either.

Comment: @Perguntador mine is a more elemental answer.